# riscv and hardware random generator

Tags: random, riscv

I don't know much about RISCV (actually thinking about Open RISC) and what little I have read tells it is about creating and optimizing things. Now people (FSF for instance) has suspected time and again that security forces may be giving weak random number generators and whatever passwords are generated could be broken by them easily.

While I don't know whether to believe that or not, from what little I read, it seemed RISC might be a platform which may make and have lot of improvements in random number generator (creation and secrecy both). Is this true or just fanciful thoughts ?

Answer (score 1):

RISC-V and OpenRISC are Instruction Set Architectures (ISA) and have nothing to do with random number generators. Although an ISA can have dedicated instructions for generating random numbers. 
Everything that is security related can be attacked in different ways like side channel attacks or timing attacks. Those attacks depend on the hardware and software implementations and not on the ISA.